# ctrl+alt+f1( or f2...) is a black screen. (Ubuntu20.04, Gnome, gdm3)

Tags: 20.04, gdm, virtual-console

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS startup with gdm3 can normally show the login window.[image]
But, When I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>( or <kbd>f2</kbd>...), the screen goes black.[image]
I'm a beginner. I've tried every "fix" I've found online, but to no avail. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Do you see a cogwheel icon on bottom right corner before login.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that kernel had disable "CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE" . So enable it solved my problem.